# I am trying to define a range in the case clause of the switch statement in dart but unable to set it right

Tags: dart, switch-statement, case

I need to define an age range in the case clause of the switch statement where the first case should be a number between 1 to 17 for the function to print " you are underage" and other case statements. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
import'dart:io';

void main(){
  print ("Enter your age: ");
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  switch (age){

    case underage <=17:
      print ("You are not allowed to enter");
      break;

    case ofage >=18 && ofage <=35:
      print ("You are eligible to enter");
      break;
    case mature >35 && mature <= 55:
      print ("welcome");
      break;
    default:
      print ("You must go to RSL Club");
  }
}
```

But this is not working. Please tell me how to define this range within the case clause or and other sub function under the case clause.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible. The Dart `switch` statement's `case` clauses can only be single values which are compared with the switched-on value by equality.

The only way you can make this work with a switch case is using:

```dart
switch (age) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
  ...
  case 17:
    print ("You are not allowed to enter");
    break;
  case 18:
  case 19:
  ...
  case 35:
    print ("You are eligible to enter");
    break;
  case 36:
  .. etc ..
```

Not really viable.

Just use `if` statements:

```dart
if (age < 18) {
  print("You are not allowed to enter");
} else if (age <= 35) {
  print("You are eligible to enter");
} else if (age <= 55) {
  print("welcome");
} else {
  print ("You must go to RSL Club");
}
```